# Macbook Air, Mac Mail - 12h instead of 24h clock in replies

Tags: mail.app, time

I have my system preferences set to a **24h clock** on my Macbook Air, using Mojave.

In Mac mail, the emails I send and receive show the time in 24h clock format in their headers.

However, when I reply to mails, the emails included in my reply show the 12h clock format (AM/PM) in their headers.

How do I ensure that the **24h format** is used throughout Mac mail usage?

Thank you.

Comment: When you say "the emails included in my reply show the 12h clock format (AM/PM) in their headers" do you mean the quoted part of the message you replied to, like "On Feb 15, 2019, at 9:14 AM, Fred@foo.com wrote:" or do you mean the information in the headers of the email message, by the Message-ID and MIME-Version headers?

Comment: Yes, indeed, I wasn't clear. I mean't the quoted part of the mail message, to which I replied. Eg, : Sent: February 16, 2019 at 8:30:07 PM GMT+1 appears, instead of Sent: February 16, 2019 at 20:30:07 GMT+1